# How can I write a Regex with matching groups for a comma separated string

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I've got a random input string to validate and tokenize.

My aim is to check if my string has the following pattern

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2} (one or unlimited times) comma separated

So:
aa12,af43,ad46 -> is valid
,aa12,aa44 -> is NOT valid (initial comma)
aa12, -> is NOT valid ( trailing comma)
```

That's the first part, validation
Then, with the same regex I've got to create a group for each occurrence of the pattern (match collection)

So:

```
aa12,af34,tg53
is valid and must create the following groups
Group 1 -> aa12
Group 2 -> af34
Group 3 -> tg53
```

Is it possible to have it done with only one regex that validates and creates the groups?

I've written this

```
    ^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2})(?:(?:[,])([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2})(?:[,])([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}))*(?:[,])([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2})*|$
```

but even if it creates the groups more or less correctly, it lacks in the validation process, getting also strings that have a wrong pattern.

Any hints would be very very welcome

Comment: *(one or unlimited times)* - it means you can have any number of csv strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```cs
var text = "aa12,af43,ad46";
var pattern = @"^(?:([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2})(?:,\b|$))+$";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value))
        .ToList();
foreach (var list in result)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", list));
# => aa12; af43; ad46
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/cIBzTT) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%5ba-zA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5cd%7b2%7d%29%28%3f%3a%2c%5cb%7c%5cr%3f%24%29%29%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=aa12%2caf43%2cad46%0d%0a%2caa12%2caa44%0d%0aaa12%2c%0d%0aaa12aa44&o=m).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2})(?:,\b|$))+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2})` - Group 1: two ASCII letter and then two digits
  - `(?:,\b|$)` - either `,` followed with a word char or end of string
- `$` - end of string. You may use `\z` if you want to prevent matching trailing newlines, LF, chars.

Comment: You have an error because the groups include the comma when it is present and they are supposed to exclude it. I would suggest `\b` is better described as "the start of a word" or "a word boundary".

Comment: @NetMage The typo was in the regex demo, not in the online code. And `\b` here means `,` must be followed with a word char.